# How to logout from wifi network

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, login-screen, wireless-hotspot

I use wifi given to me By my institute.There is a limitation of 3 devices at a time.I have 2 laptop and 2 mobile phones.At times I need to properly disconnect so that one of my device I disconnect and connect another one.Unfortunately I don't find a way to properly disconnect/logout from wifi system. What I do maximum is from my android mobile phone I just press the wifi icon which disconnects it from wifi system but does not logs out.As a result if I want to use another device in place of previously connected device I am unable to do so.I get a message on new device saying "You have reached maximum login limit" 
[image].
The institute uses Sophos to and a login page opens as soon as my laptop or mobile is connected which does not have a log out option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Sophos forums:

- https://community.sophos.com/products/xg-firewall/f/authentication/74694/i-need-a-logout-button-for-the-captive-portal-or-a-url-i-can-bookmark
- https://community.sophos.com/products/xg-firewall/f/authentication/90630/using-captive-portal-how-can-i-log-off

there isn't a user-accessible logout option; the network admins would have to build it on their own first.

Comment: A very dodgy work-arround may be to assign the same MAC address to the laptop as the WIFI uses - as long as only 1 device used at a time.